# How to draw a contour plot on the map? [Tableau]

Tags: tableau-api

I have some spatial data sets for [PM2_5]. Could anybody teach me how to draw a contour plot on the map? Also, how to use the interpolation algorithm implemented in the software with that?[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly1ms.jpg)